# Como passar imagens entre Activities?

Tags: android

Tenho uma lista (RecyclerView) com dois textos e duas imagens em cada item. No onClick consigo passar os textos porém não as imagens. Já tentei de várias formas e o que cheguei mais perto foi com o seguinte:

Passando...

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

    TextView txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nome_cientifico);  
    String str = txt.getText().toString();

    TextView txt1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nome_comum);  
    String str1 = txt1.getText().toString();

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.slide1);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    byte[] jovens = stream.toByteArray();

    Bitmap bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.slide3);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream1);
    byte[] adultas = stream1.toByteArray();

    Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(), Detalhes.class);

    intent.putExtra("CIENTIFICO", str);

    intent.putExtra("COMUM", str1);

    intent.putExtra("IMAGEMJ", jovens);

    intent.putExtra("IMAGEMA", adultas);

    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Recebendo....

```
Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detalhes, container, false);

if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra("CIENTIFICO")) {

    mMato = intent.getStringExtra("CIENTIFICO");
    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(mMato);

    mMato1 = intent.getStringExtra("COMUM");
    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView2)).setText(mMato1);

    byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("IMAGEMJ");
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    image.setImageBitmap(bmp);

    byte[] byteArray1 = extras.getByteArray("IMAGEMA");
    Bitmap bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray1, 0, byteArray1.length);
    ImageView image1 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    image1.setImageBitmap(bmp1);
}
```

O meu problema é com a imagem R.drawable.slide1 e R.drawable.slide3 Passando assim elas ficam fixas para cada item clicado e não passa as imagens referentes ao item.

Comment: Tem que ser a imagem propriamente dita? Não pode ser sua referencia?

Comment: Oi Diego Felipe, Pode sim ser a referencia.Muito obrigado pela atenção. Estou ficando louco com isso cara.

Comment: Poste o código desse `onClick()`

Comment: Se entendi bem sua dúvida, as imagens sempre ficam iguais à `R.drawable.slide1`, correto? Não seria só mudar `Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.slide1);` para `Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), clickedImageView.getId());`? Onde `clickedImageView` seria a `View` do método `onClick(View)`.

Comment: @RubenO.Chiavone Não quer colocar uma resposta? Eu dei uma alternativa mas está com problemas devido ao tamanho das imagens. Julgo que a sua sugestão resolve o problema.

Comment: Modesto Barreto, qual `Listener` é esse que tem o callback `onItemClick(View, int)`? E como você adiciona ele no `RecyclerView`?

Answer (score 2):

O que você tem de fazer é passar o *Bitmap* que está na *ImageView* do item da lista.
Da mesma forma que faz para os *TextView* obtenha a referência para a *ImageView*:

```
ImgeView slide1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.slide1);//Altere para o R.id correcto
```

Obtenha o *Bitmap* da *ImageView* da seguinte forma:

```
Bitmap jovens =((BitmapDrawable)slide1.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

A classe [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) implementa a interface *Parcelable* podendo seus objectos serem passados em um *Bundle*:

```
intent.putExtra("IMAGEMJ", jovens);
```

Para receber faça:

```
Bitmap jovem = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("IMAGEMJ");
ImageView image = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
image.setImageBitmap(jovem);
```

Comment: Oi ramaral. Fiz tudo direitinho mas ele retorna um erro. Quando clico no item ele dá o seguinte: E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!.

Comment: Isso é devido à imagem(bitmap) ser muito grande. Deverá comprimi-la/reduzi-la antes de a colocar na ImageView.

Comment: Onde obtém essas imagens?

Comment: Estão na pasta drawable e antes eu compactei como documento. Mas acho que é isso mesmo. Tentei compactar como fiz no código anterior mas não consegui. Se achar necessário posso colocar aqui como fiz. Mais uma vez Obrigado.

Comment: Cada uma tem de 50 a 90 k

Comment: Veja o comentário que o @RubenO.Chiavone deixou na pergunta.

Comment: Eu já tinha visto e tentado mas não deu certo. Minha lista não tem ID. Tentei colocar mas não deu certo. De qualquer forma muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Se sabes qual a imagem que está associada ao item que clicas então podes fazer assim:

Passando...

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(), Detalhes.class);
int imageId = R.drawable.slide1; // Aqui tens de mudar dinamicamente (de acordo com o item que clicas) para a imagem que pretendes passar para os detalhes
intent.putExtra("IMAGEMJ", imageId );

startActivity(intent);
```

Recebendo....

```
int imageId= extras.getInt("IMAGEMJ");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imageId);
ImageView image = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: Oi Victor, Meu problema é justamente esse. Não sei como mudar dinamicamente. Claro que sei qual a imagem está associada ao item. Obrigado pelo interesse.

Comment: Em algum momento tu tiveste de construir um adapter para alimentar a RecyclerView. Nesse adapater concerteza que lhe passaste uma List<> ou um ArrayList<> de um determinado objeto criado por ti para esse RecyclerView.

A unica forma de a tua RecyclerView mostar imagens é se nesse cada objeto da List<> ou ArrayList<> que tu passaste ao adapter conter  uma referencia da imagem R.drawable.nome_da_imagem.

Desta forma podes usar o valor ´position´ que o metodo onItemClick() te devolve para acederes ao objecto da tua List<>/ArrayList<> e assim conseguir obter essa imagem.

Comment: Oi Victor, Desculpe mas eu estava em viagem de trabalho e só vi sua sugestão hoje. Deu certo para a primeira imagem, mas só passa até a 5ª, da nº 6 em diante ele fecha o aplicativo. Também quando adiciono a segunda imagem ele fecha. Talvez seja porque minha lista é muito grande? Tenho 179 itens.

Comment: Podes me mostrar qual o error? E já a agora também é util se me mostrares a parte do código onde ocorre o erro.

Comment: Oi Victor, Ele não dava mensagem, simplesmente fechava.

Comment: O código tinha ficado assim:                                                          Bitmap bmpj = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), mEspecie.get(position).getPhotoIDj());
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmpj.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                byte[] jovens = stream.toByteArray();                                              O que fiz e funcionou foi o seguinte: Mudei o 100 pra 50 e dei um tamanho fixo para os 2 ImageView 330 por 250 que estava wrap_content

Comment: já deu uma olhada no android monitor para ver se nn deu **out of memory**?